# Add operator overloading to TypeScript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, operator-overloading, language-server-protocol

I am working on a project which requires a lot of vector and matrix math and I would *love* to have operator overloading.

There are Babel plugins (for example https://github.com/rob-blackbourn/jetblack-operator-overloading) that enable operator overloading for JavaScript but they don't work with TypeScript (or at least they don't work with the TS language sever for VS Code). There are workarounds using `// @ts-ignore` but I find it ugly and it removes the benefits of type checking for the next line.

I would like to convert the code like this (where `a`, `b`, and `c` are custom objects):

```js
a + b * c
```

To something like this:

```js
a.__add__(b.__mul__(c))
```

And if, for example, `c` is of the wrong type for function `__mul__`, VS Code should underline the original line or even better the symbol `c`.

I imagine it would be possible to transform the code before passing it to the TS compiler (that is exactly what the Babel plugin does). But VS Code would always show the error (`Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'Custom' and 'Custom'`).

**So my question is**: is there a project that achieves the above described behavior? If not is it possible to extend TypeScript and/or TypeScript language server in this way? If so please provide links to references for further research.

I am also interested in how JSX (used in React) with completely new syntax achieves full integration with TS and is there any other project that modifies TS in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Babel only works on javascript code and you'll need to write a customized typescript transformer and configured this transformer on ts-loader. But still one problem may raises when the ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin checks your syntax correctness. Maybe you'll have to close this plugin.

Below is an example code for creating an null transformer:

```js
export function createTransformer (): ts.TransformerFactory<ts.SourceFile> {
  console.log("Hello, I am transformer just created");
  return (context: ts.TransformationContext) => {
    return (sourceFile: ts.SourceFile) => {
      function visit (node: ts.Node): ts.Node {
      return ts.visitNode(sourceFile, visit)
    }
  }
}
export default createTransformer
```

Besides, you'll have to configure your project, if in vue, the vue.config.js would be:

```
const PipeTransformer = require('./pipe-transformer').default


module.exports = {
  // .... other configurations 
  chainWebpack: config => {
    // Can not use the ts-pipe-operator plugin, the babel plugin process only javascript not typescript.
    config.module.rule('ts').use('ts-loader').tap(options => {
      options.transpileOnly = true
      options.appendTsSuffixTo = ['\\.vue$']
      options.happyPackMode = false
      options.getCustomTransformers = () => ({
        before: [PipeTransformer()]
      })
      return options
    })
  }
}
```